# Import Ionic Icons in html

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How Can I  import ionic icons in a simple HTML page? I've downloaded the package from the official website but I don't know where to import it from HTML .

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the CDN, in which case all you have to do is include the stylesheet (the fonts will also be loaded from the CDN, via the stylesheet)

```html
<link crossorigin="anonymous" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />

<i class="ion-happy"></i>
<i class="ion-help-buoy"></i>
```

Or you can copy all the files locally, then you have to download the [fonts](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/tree/master/fonts) as well from the official repo.[enter link description here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons)